# How to make sure only one row is enabled?

Tags: django, django-models

My webapp has a bunch of configuration parameters for certain backend tasks. These configuration parameters are stored in the database, so that they can easily be edited via the admin.

I want to offer the option to experiment with several settings, but there is one constraint: only one row must be enabled.

How can I make sure that only one row is enabled? How can I offer an interface in the admin to choose which row is enabled?

Please note that I do not want to limit the number of possible configuration rows to one: I do want to offer the option of having several parameter sets, but only one must be active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `pre_save` signal for that model. In there if you see that the `enabled` flag is set to true, you query on all configs currently are enabled. You disable all of them and save current instance:

```
def unique_enabled(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.enabled:
        for other in Config.objects.filter(enabled=True).exclude(id=instance.id):
            other.enabled = False
            other.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting. It is worth noting that `unique_enabled` will be called for all objects that we are disabling too (but will do nothing, since `enabled` is false)